# E: Unable to locate package sqlite; docker

Tags: docker, debian, apt

I ran into this issue when using a docker container. The aggravating thing is that it was working fine on another computer, and when I went back to check, it was still working.

The root image I'm using is `php:7.3-fpm`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that `php:7.3-fpm` silently updated Debian to the most recent version (as of this writing that's 11), in which the `sqlite` package is no longer available. So if you're running into `Unable to Locate package <packagename>`, check the underlying OS distribution. I solved it by checking the apt-cache (`apt-cache search sqlite`) and noticing the package was indeed missing.

I solved it by using the specific Debian version, which thankfully is available: `php:7.3-fpm-buster`